# Shell script to cut /proc/softirqs

Tags: shell, awk, cut

The following is output of  "cat /proc/softirqs "  :

```
                    CPU0       CPU1       CPU2       CPU3
          HI:         24         13          7         54
       TIMER:  344095632  253285150  121234786  108207697
      NET_TX:    2366955        319        695     316044
      NET_RX:   16337920   16030558  250497436  117201444
       BLOCK:      19631       2747       2353    5067051
BLOCK_IOPOLL:          0          0          0          0
     TASKLET:        298         93        157      20965
       SCHED:   74354472   28133393   30646119   26217748
     HRTIMER: 4123645358 2409060621 2466360502  401470590
         RCU:   26083738   17708780   15330534   16857905
```

My another machine has 24 cpu cores and the output is hard to read ,
I like the output to be  only cpu0 , cpu2 , cpu4 , cpu6, ....
I know cut or awk might be ued to do that , 
but no idea how to use it to get even output columns .

Edit :

```
awk -F" " '{printf("%10s\t%s\n", $2,$4) }'
```

will get

```
      CPU1  CPU3
        24  7
 344095632  121234786
   2366955  695
  16337920  250497436
     19631  2353
         0  0
       298  157
  74354472  30646119
4123645358  2466360502
  26083738  15330534
```

unfortunately , CPU1 should be CPU0  , CPU3  should be CPU2  ,
the first line has only 4 columns , may I skip the first line
in this shell ?!

Edit2 :

```
watch -d "cat /proc/softirqs | awk -F" " '{printf("%10s\t%s\n",$2,$4)}' "
```

encounter errors like the following :

```
Every 2.0s: cat /proc/softirqs | awk -F  '{print    }' Tue Jun 21 10:23:22 2016

Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] -f progfile [--] file ...
Usage: awk [POSIX or GNU style options] [--] 'program' file ...
POSIX options:          GNU long options: (standard)
        -f progfile             --file=progfile
        -F fs                   --field-separator=fs
        -v var=val              --assign=var=val
Short options:          GNU long options: (extensions)
        -b                      --characters-as-bytes
        -c                      --traditional
        -C                      --copyright
        -d[file]                --dump-variables[=file]
        -e 'program-text'   --source='program-text'
        -E file                 --exec=file
        -g                      --gen-pot
        -h                      --help
        -L [fatal]              --lint[=fatal]
        -n                      --non-decimal-data
        -N                      --use-lc-numeric
        -O                      --optimize
        -p[file]                --profile[=file]
        -P                      --posix
        -r                      --re-interval
        -S                      --sandbox
        -t                      --lint-old
        -V                      --version

To report bugs, see node `Bugs' in `gawk.info', which is
section `Reporting Problems and Bugs' in the printed version.

gawk is a pattern scanning and processing language.
By default it reads standard input and writes standard output.

Examples:
        gawk '{ sum += $1 }; END { print sum }' file
        gawk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

what else should I try ?!

Edit3 :

The final workable shell would like :

```
# define function encapsulating code; this prevents any need for extra layers of quoting
# or escaping.
run() {
    awk  'NR>1{printf("%20s\t%10s\t%s\n",$1,$2,$4)}' </proc/softirqs|egrep 'TIMER|RX'
}

# export function
export -f run

# run function in subshell of watch, ensuring that that shell is bash
# (other shells may not honor exported functions)
watch -d  "bash -c run"
```

Comment: If you want to escape a string of shell code to pass it to `watch`, `printf %q` is your friend -- or just put it in a script; `watch` -- which performs a new `sh -c` run on every refresh -- is sufficiently inefficient that you're not losing much by a single additional shell invocation.

Comment: That said, asking how to escape things for `watch` should be its own question, rather than melded into this one; arguably you've made the question as it exists too broad to fit within site rules, since it now has two completely different questions contained, and an answer would need to span both to be fully responsive.

Comment: ...or, if you have code you like and just want to know how to run it from `watch`, that's acceptable too; it's trying to both get the formatting code and run it from `watch` in one question that's overbroad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to communicate code to a subprocess of `watch` that avoids escaping errors is to use an exported function:

```
# define function encapsulating code; this prevents any need for extra layers of quoting
# or escaping.
run() {
  awk -F" " '{printf("%10s\t%s\n",$2,$4)}' </proc/softirqs
}

# export function
export -f run

# run function in subshell of watch, ensuring that that shell is bash
# (other shells may not honor exported functions)
watch "bash -c run"
```

---

To avoid the dependency on exported functions, one can also use `declare -f` to retrieve the function's source in an `eval`able form, and `printf %q` to escape it to survive processing by the outer shell invoked by `watch`:

```
run() {
  awk -F" " '{printf("%10s\t%s\n",$2,$4)}' </proc/softirqs
}
printf -v run_str '%q' "$(declare -f run); run"
watch "bash -c $run_str"
```

Answer (score 0):

To skip the first line, do:

```
awk -F" " 'NR>1{printf("%10s\t%s\n", $2,$4) }'
```

Why do you need `-F" "`, is a mystery to me.  You can as well write:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf("%10s\t%s\n", $2,$4) }'
```

(As for the `watch` part, see other answer/s.)

Comment: Indeed it doesn't work. Removed the watch part.  Without watch, it works.

Comment: Yup. This is why I still hold that how to format this, and how to make it work in `watch`, should be two completely separate questions.